# TSQL query to gather amounts for an employees, spouses, and children in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that works as intended, kind of pulling from multiple records in a table, and flattening the data into one row. I am wondering if there is a faster/more semantically correct way to do this than multiple derived tables?

```
ID      Name      Relationship      Amount
-------------------------------------------
1       James     Employee           2000
1       James     Spouse             5000
1       James     Child             10000
2       Mary      Employee           2000
3       Pete      Employee           2000
3       Pete      Child             10000
3       Pete      Child             10000
```

And turning it into:

```
ID      Name      EmployeeAmt      SpouseAmt      ChildAmt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       James     2000             5000           10000
2       Mary      2000             NULL           NULL
3       Pete      2000             NULL           10000
```

Here is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Source
(
   EmpID varchar(2) NULL
   ,Name varchar(20) NULL
   ,Relationship varchar(20) NULL
   ,Amount varchar(10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Source
VALUES( '1', 'James', 'Child', 10000)
     ,('1', 'James', 'Spouse', 5000)
     ,('1', 'James', 'EE', 2000)
     ,('2', 'Mary', 'EE', 2000)
     ,('3', 'Pete', 'EE', 2000)
     ,('3', 'Pete', 'Child', 10000)
     ,('3', 'Pete', 'Child', 10000)

SELECT DISTINCT A.EmpID, A.Name, A.EEAmount, B.SpouseAmount, C.ChildAmount
FROM (
          SELECT EmpID, Name, Relationship, Amount AS 'EEAmount'
          FROM #Source
          WHERE Relationship = 'EE'
     ) AS A

     LEFT JOIN

    (
          SELECT EmpID, Name, Relationship, Amount AS 'SpouseAmount'
          FROM #Source
          WHERE Relationship = 'Spouse'
    ) AS B ON A.EmpID = B.EmpID

    LEFT JOIN 

    (
          SELECT EmpID, Name, Relationship, Amount AS 'ChildAmount'
          FROM #Source
          WHERE Relationship = 'Child'
    ) AS C ON A.EmpID = C.EmpID

SELECT * FROM #Source
DROP TABLE #Source
```

Comment: What if an employee has more than one child? (or more than one spouse?)

Comment: In this instance, that is irrelevant. The amount will stay the same.

Comment: I would expect two rows in the output for Pete, if the child amounts are different?

Comment: Those amounts are static, they will never change.  I should have substituted Amount for something else. Amount--while it truly what will be in the final data--is confusing. Such is life when dealing with insurance.

Comment: So, the amount for an employee is always 2000, the amount for a spouse is always 5000, and the amount for a child is always 10000, and only the existence (and not the number) of each kind of dependant is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, all of those `LEFT JOIN`s are unwieldy.  On top of that, the joins create phantom rows in the result that you have to deduplicate with `DISTINCT`.

The solution is to treat this as an aggregation problem rather than a join.  You want to `GROUP BY` the employee.

```
SELECT EmpId
     , Name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Relationship = 'EE'     THEN Amount END) AS EmployeeAmt
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Relationship = 'Spouse' THEN Amount END) AS SpouseAmt
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Relationship = 'Child'  THEN Amount END) AS ChildAmt
    FROM #Source
    GROUP BY EmpId, Name
    ORDER BY EmpId;
```

See this [demo](//data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/462230/code-review-question-124215).

---

I would also like to note that using single-quoted strings as a column alias (`Amount AS 'EEAmount'`) is sloppy.  [T-SQL identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) should be unquoted, "doublequoted", or [bracketed].  For ANSI compliance and compatibility, either [use double-quotes](//stackoverflow.com/q/1992314/1157100), or don't quote the alias at all.

Comment: Also, thank you for the back and fourth questions on the initial question. That helps me to now see that I need to be every explicit. Little bits of information do help, like being able to use MAX() to filter out duplicates because numbers in Amount are static. Which wouldn't have been known if you hadn't pulled it out of me :)

Comment: 200_success, Mincong's answer below uses the PIVOT, which seems well suited for my situation also. As he mentions he is new to PIVOT tables as well, I am wondering if you could explain the merits of PIVOT vs your solution, if there are any?

Comment: PIVOT is less portable: [it works in SQL Server and Oracle, but is not specified in ANSI SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4842726/1157100). PostgreSQL does it completely differently, using `crosstab()`, and MySQL doesn't have anything like it. Conceptually, PIVOT is awkward in that it blurs the lines between string data and column identifiers. On the other hand, PIVOT is arguably a closer description of what the query aims to achieve (classifying the data of one column into multiple columns).

Answer (score 3):

You can use T-SQL's operator [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do this.

```
SELECT EmpID, Name, [EE], [Spouse], [Child]
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpID, Name, Relationship, CAST(Amount AS INT) AS AmountINT 
    FROM Source
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AmountINT)
    --
    -- Define your target relationships here
    -- EE, Spouse, Child ...
    -- These relationships should be exactly the same as described in
    -- the SELECT statement
    -- 
    FOR Relationship IN ([EE], [Spouse], [Child]) 
) AS PivotTable;
```

**Result**

```
EmpID   Name    EE      Spouse  Child
1       James   2000    5000    10000
2       Mary    2000    NULL    NULL
3       Pete    2000    NULL    10000
```

You need to cast your `Amount` into numeric type before doing so.

Comment: Going to look into this as an alternate soon. Thanks!

Comment: So, my situation seems to be what the PIVOT was made for. What are the merits to using PIVOT vs 200_Success's answer above?

Comment: Is the PIVOT perhaps more robust than I need in this situation?

Comment: Actually, I'm new to PIVOT as well. I'll study more about this operator and reply you when I return to company tomorrow. @Jeff.Clark

Comment: This actually gives the wrong result for Pete's children. The desired `ChildAmt` is 10000 if Pete has any children; he doesn't get another 10000 for the second child.

Comment: @200_success You're right. I didn't notice this point. Should it work if we use `MAX()` instead of `SUM()` ?

Comment: @Jeff.Clark I don't really know which is better for you. No idea for robustness. Certainly, 200_success has reason for the partability. As for the performance, PIVOT (6ms) is better than CASE WHEN (13ms) for your example dataset. Could you tell me the result for your real dataset ? I'm curious to know it :)